# Lookup all rows from another table in excel

Tags: excel

I am using Excel 2013. I have a table in excel that is linked to an Access Database. This table has a list of vendor_id along with other statistics for each vendor. I want to create a new table in excel that pulls every vendor_id from the first table. Anyone have any idea how to do this? I was going to just use an = function to copy every row but when I update the old table, I would have to manually change the size of the new table.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Data"->"From Table" and reference the relevant rows in your existing table.

Only have a German Excel handy, sorry:
[image]

English Version:

[image]

Comment: there is no data > from table

Comment: Which Excel-version are you using?

Comment: Added an English version, If you do not want it, feel free to roll back.

Comment: i am using excel 2013. is there the same function for this version?